# Using CSS for alternate row shading in paragraph (<p> ... NOT a table)

Tags: css

Is it possible to do alternating row shading in a paragraph element where the rows are wrapped? There is no `:nth-child` technique here, because we're only talking about one element. For example if we had,

```html
<p style="width:100px;">
row 0 -- hello
row 1 -- world
row 2 -- !!!
</p>
```

My browser does a "soft return" after "hello" and "world", causing the above rows of text to end up looking the same as they do above (at least when I render it in my browser).

What I would like is for rows 0 and 2 to be different colors (shadded) than row 1, just like it is in a table when using `tr:nth-child(even)` when creating a table with alternating colored rows.

Is this possible? Or is there a practical alternative approach using different elements (without having to chop up the paragraph myself and stick it in a table!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color them with a repeating gradient:

```css
p {
  line-height:1.2em; /* height of one line */
  color:transparent;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, red 0 1.2em,grey 0 2.4em);
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  background-clip:text;
}
```

```html
<p style="width:100px;">
row 0 -- hello
row 1 -- world
row 2 -- !!!
row 3 -- hello
row 4 -- world
and so on
</p>
```

Another syntax:

```css
p {
  line-height:1.2em; /* height of one line */
  color:transparent;
  background:linear-gradient(180deg, red 50%,grey 0) 0 0/100% 2.4em;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  background-clip:text;
}
```

```html
<p style="width:100px;">
row 0 -- hello
row 1 -- world
row 2 -- !!!
row 3 -- hello
row 4 -- world
and so on
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a programmatic JavaScript solution that creates an unordered list out of the lines in your paragraph by detecting line break `\n` symbols.

```js
var pRows = document.getElementById('p-rows');

pRows.innerHTML = pRows.innerHTML
  .split('\n')
  .join('</li><li>')
  .replace(/^<\/li>/, '<ul>')
  .replace(/<li>$/, '</ul>')
```

```css
#p-rows ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#p-rows li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<p id="p-rows">
row 0 -- hello
row 1 -- world
row 2 -- !!!
row 3 -- ???
row 4 -- ***
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's quite tricky tho!

```css
p {
  background-clip: text;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( red, blue, red);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p style="width:100px;">
row 0 -- hello
row 1 -- world
row 2 -- !!!
</p>
```